# Difference between cupy.asnumpy() and get()

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

Given a CuPy array `a`, there are two ways to get a numpy array from it: `a.get()` and `cupy.asnumpy(a)`.  Is there any practical difference between them?

```
import cupy as cp

a = cp.random.randint(10, size=(4,5,6,7))

b = a.get()
c = cp.asnumpy(a)

assert type(b) == type(c) and (b == c).all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp.asnumpy` is a wrapper calling `ndarray.get`. You can see that in the code of `cp.asnumpy`:

```py
def asnumpy(a, stream=None, order='C', out=None):
    """Returns an array on the host memory from an arbitrary source array.

    Args:
        a: Arbitrary object that can be converted to :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
        stream (cupy.cuda.Stream): CUDA stream object. If it is specified, then
            the device-to-host copy runs asynchronously. Otherwise, the copy is
            synchronous. Note that if ``a`` is not a :class:`cupy.ndarray`
            object, then this argument has no effect.
        order ({'C', 'F', 'A'}): The desired memory layout of the host
            array. When ``order`` is 'A', it uses 'F' if ``a`` is
            fortran-contiguous and 'C' otherwise.
        out (numpy.ndarray): The output array to be written to. It must have
            compatible shape and dtype with those of ``a``'s.

    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: Converted array on the host memory.

    """
    if isinstance(a, ndarray):
        return a.get(stream=stream, order=order, out=out)
    elif hasattr(a, "__cuda_array_interface__"):
        return array(a).get(stream=stream, order=order, out=out)
    else:
        temp = _numpy.asarray(a, order=order)
        if out is not None:
            out[...] = temp
        else:
            out = temp
        return out
```

As you can see (both in the documentation and in the code), `cp.asnumpy` supports more input types than just CuPy arrays. It supports inputs that are CUDA objects with the `__cuda_array_interface__` attribute and any objects that can be actually converted to a Numpy array. This includes Numpy arrays themselves and iterables (eg. list, generators, etc.).